# How to check if a model is present in an Array in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an array, and the elements inside are a mix of 2 models: `Article` and `Profile`.

Is there a way to check if there is an `Article` and/or `Profile` model inside the array? The functions I saw like `include?` work for the specific elements and not their class.

Example:
Given `[Profile1, Profile2, Article1]` I wanted to check if there is an `Article` or `Profile` in there. I can only check if there is an element named `Profile1`.

Any help would be much appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: _"I can only check if there is an element named Profile1."_ – how does that check look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution:

you can simply check whether the array contains Profile object using:

```
array = [Profile1, Profile2, Article1]
array.any?(Profile)
```

and similarly for Article:

`array.any?(Article)`

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You can use the method [any?](https://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/any%3F) with the method [is_a?](https://apidock.com/ruby/Object/is_a%3F)

Here is a way to know if there is an `Article` or a `Profile` in the array.

```rb
array = [Profile1, Profile2, Article1]
array.any? { |a| a.is_a?(Article) || a.is_a?(Profile) }
```

Comment: There's also `array.any?(Article)` which checks whether `array` contains an instance of (actually `kind_of?`) `Article`.

Answer (score 0):

You can even use [instance_of?](https://apidock.com/ruby/v2_5_5/Object/instance_of%3F)

```
array = [Profile1, Profile2, Article1]
array.any?{ |v| v.instance_of?(Profile) || v.instance_of?(Article) }
```

If you want count every models, you can do like this:

For Article

```
array = [Profile1, Profile2, Article1]
array.map{ |v| v.instance_of?(Article) }.count(true)
```

For Profile

```
array.map{ |v| v.instance_of?(Profile) }.count(true)
```